# How can I get horizontal line of navigation dots in header of Singapore beamer theme?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, themes, navigation

I'm writing a presentation using the `Singapore` theme.

The dots in the navigation bar are appearing vertically (one below the other)  rather than horizontally. This is consuming a lot of space of my frames and is even not looking good presentation wise.

I have seen presentations using this theme where the dots appear horizontally. How can I do this?[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `compress` option for the `Singapore` theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[compress]{Singapore}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting headline:

[image]

Comment: Thats work perfectly !

Comment: A link to reference (where the option is explained) would be a nice touch.