# Beamer group navigation dots per section

Tags: beamer, navigation

Similar to the question (and MWE) asked in the link below, I would like to organise my navigation bullets horizontally per section. However, in addition, I would like to group the bullet points by subsection.

hence, instead of:

Section 1

ooooooooooo

I would like to have

Section 1

ooo ooo ooo oo

Where the dots are grouped by subsection. I am using the Singapore theme.

[How can I get horizontal line of navigation dots in header of Singapore beamer theme?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156695/how-can-i-get-horizontal-line-of-navigation-dots-in-header-of-singapore-beamer-t)